# SDL Audio Channel not functioning as per requirement

Tags: c, sdl

We have a snippet of SDL codes as below.

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
atexit(SDL_Quit);
g_pDisplaySurface =
SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,0,SDL_ANYFORMAT);
g_SpecDesired=new SDL_AudioSpec;
g_SpecObtained=new SDL_AudioSpec;
g_SpecDesired->freq=22050;
g_SpecDesired->format=AUDIO_U8; 
g_SpecDesired->channels=1;
g_SpecDesired->samples=8192;
g_SpecDesired->callback=FOSDLAudioCallback;
g_SpecDesired->userdata=NULL;
```

The callback function is

```
void FOSDLAudioCallback(void* userdata,Uint8* buffer,int len)
{
    int index;
    printf("LEn is :%d",&len);
    for(index=0;index<len;index++)
    {
    buffer[index]=rand()%256;
    }
}
```

The problem here even we change channel to either 1 or 2 it still play on both stereo channel? Why does it behave in this manner?

Comment: Where is your SDL_OpenAudioDevice()? Also, why using new on AudioSpec structures? You need them once, it's better be placed on stack.

Comment: @keltar I have updated with the call back function. I am doing a very rough test no SDL_OpenAudioDevice(). Later examples I am using them.

Comment: I don't get it. You have no OpenAudioDevice()? Then you have no audio. How do you verifying that you've still got 2 channels (btw, it's not guaranteed that you'll get what you've requested, that's why you have `desired` and `obtained`)? You should check `obtained` structure fields. Or is your question is why you're hearing sound from two speakers while you've opened mono device?

Comment: Yes why i am hearing sound from two speakers when I have opened only 1 channel which suppose to be mono device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `obtained` says it's mono - it's mono. Which means not how many speakers you have, but how many channels. For mono, you may have any number of speakers (let's say 6), but you cannot, but any mean, play different sounds on them - only one channel, so all speakers play the same sound at each moment of time.

It's audio driver's job to interpolate it according to it's settings. For higher number of channels, it could be even trickier - driver could split stereo to 5.1 or so.

If you want to play sound only on, say, left speaker, you should create maximum available context and use corresponding 'left' speaker.

Here is modified version of your callback that fills second channel to 0 (full silence) (requires 2 channels audio mode and AUDIO_U8 - modify initialisation to match this):

```
void FOSDLAudioCallback(void* userdata,Uint8* buffer,int len)
{
    int index;
    printf("LEn is :%d",&len);
    for(index=0;index<len;index++)
    {
        buffer[index]= (index % 2) ? rand()%256 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @But then all the documentation claim to have mono equal to 1 channels that is confusing here rite. So I have set this g_SpecObtained->channels=1;
SDL_OpenAudio(g_SpecDesired,g_SpecObtained);
//delete g_SpecDesired;
SDL_PauseAudio(0); but yet its playing on both speakers.

Comment: Mono is 1 channel indeed. Channels and speakers are completely different things. How channels mapped to speakers is up to driver. If you don't like how it does this - request highest available number of channels and use only ones you need (there is, however, no guarantee that you'll have that many speakers - let's say 7.1 audio, but only two speakers connected), then maybe - just maybe - driver wouldn't interfere.

Comment: so in this case I can never demo a mono mapping to one single channel am I right?

Comment: There is no guaranteed way, yes. Try allocating stereo and feeding silent sound to right channel - it will work most of the time, but it still could be changed by user (if driver have config - like ALSA do), by driver itself or even by hardware - e.g. some fancy USB 5.1/7.1 headsets have builtin interpolator (usually could be disabled by hardware buttons, but still). For stereo, it's usually no interference at all because most of music recorded at stereo - users will just slam driver/hardware for this interference, if it cannot be disabled, so i suppose it's your best chance.

Comment: @What do you mean by allocation stereo and feeling silen to right channel? How to code that any idea please ?

Comment: Added example to an answer, check it out.

Comment: yes it work for my right speaker but there is still some little notice on left speaker I guess is a simulation is ok. But I dont get exactly what is happening here buffer[index]= (index % 2) ? rand()%256 : 0; I know if its mod value =0 then you add value else is 0 and why is the len value is 18153168

Comment: `len` is buffer size that you need to fill. It should be something like samples*sample_size*frequency and is padded. For now, just ignore it. In buffer, data is interleaved - first sample is channel0, second is channel1, and so on, then again channel0, .... So, if you sample format is U8 - you have one byte per channel. In example i set random value to odd numbers and 0 (silence) to even numbers, so your right channel will have data to play while left channel is empty.

Comment: ok I am very clear now how it functions. So in case there is no auiod input rite. I dont get is that when say we loadwav is already in digital format so when we do sampling out of it is basically manipulating the bytes right? So back the buffer now I read some places it say set is to power of 2 is that correct? So why is my size such ?

Comment: Sorry, my memory isn't at it's best state, it appears i've provided you some false information. For silence value, you should use `obtained.silence` - it's 0x80 for U8 and 0 for S8. As for buffer size - according to SDL2 source code, it's `channels*samples`. Resulting `samples` value in `obtained` may be different - check it out first.

Comment: I am lost here so what change must I do, should I manipulate the obtained? Actually what is the obtain representing most sites I google say put it as NULL

Comment: NULL if you don't care. If not NULL, you getting fields in this structure filled according to actually initialised state - it could differ from `desired` if implementation, for some reasons, changed spec according to actual driver/hardware. So you could e.g. `printf` resulting fields in `obtained` and see if it's the same as `desired`. Please state your current question, i'm not sure what is your problem now.

Comment: my problem is still the same as earlier where I want the channel 1 to map to a single speaker so can I use your solution or should I change ?

Comment: Change it to `buffer[index]= (index % 2) ? rand()%256 : 0x80;` (if you stick with AUDIO_U8 format) - it'll remove initial 'tick' when you starting playing audio. It's not very noticable, but better do it that way.

Comment: thank you I guess this answer the question for my other question I shall open another separate thread. So do I need to set the obtained or set as null in my case just lost here not too sure ?

Comment: Well, I would've verified that results in `obtained` fits, so no NULL for me (but no `new` either! use stack), but that's just my personal opinion - i like to check everything just to be sure. If you don't want to do that (e.g. you have really small one-time demo) - pass NULL freely, it's completely ok.

Comment: in my case is jusst for a small demo so I guess just leave it as NULL will do then ?